# How to execute batch of sql statements in the QuestDB database web console?

Tags: questdb

I have bunch of insert statements copy pasted into the web console.
I selected them and pushed run button.
But only first one applied actually.

How to run all of them? Any shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way atm, I'd say it's a missing feature. You have to elect one by one and execute.